# SQLite - Order and Compare

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I want to take some columns which have specific values and order them by remaining day.Here's what i tried :

```
Statement state = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE text1 LIKE '%"book"%' "
                                   +"AND text2 LIKE '%"pencil"%' "
                                   +"AND CAST(replace(price,'.','') AS INTEGER) > 100 "
                                   +"AND ORDER BY CAST(remainingDay AS INTEGER)");
return rs;
```

But this gives `(near "ORDER": syntax error)` error.

Comment: remove `AND` before the `Order` and correct the syntax error in your string query `ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE text1 LIKE '%" + book + "%' "
        + "AND text2 LIKE '%" + pencil + "%' "
        + "AND CAST(replace(price,'.','') AS INTEGER) > 100 "
        + " ORDER BY CAST(remainingDay AS INTEGER)"
);`

Comment: Thank you a lot , it works ! :)